# How to find how much RAM memory is used on my micro:bit using makecode?

Tags: size, ram, bbc-microbit

I wrote code for my micro:bit in makecode.microbit.org. Idea is to use radio communication and send each micro:bit message. So my question at first was how many messages can get just one micro:bit?
Internet say this:
Messages received are read from a queue of configurable size (the larger the queue the more RAM is used). If the queue is full, new messages are ignored. Reading a message removes it from the queue.
So my question is: **how to find how much RAM memory is used on my micro:bit using makecode?**
edit: https://forum.makecode.com/t/how-to-find-how-much-ram-memory-is-used-on-my-micro-bit-using-makecode/1303/2
How now find length of micro:bit queue?